# Customize version different to Live version

Tags: menus

When I Customize my 'Twelve Seventeen' themed site I get the correct Top Menu and all looks good. When I come out of it the Top Menu is different. It's a menu I had created in the beginning but I can't find it to delete it.

In the old one that I want to get rid of the Class is 'menu-social-links-menu-container' 
In the one I want and that appears in the Customizer the Class is 'menu-main-menu-container'

I can include images if someone can help me.
Very frustrating.....

Comment: Have you tried going through Appearance > Menus instead? You can set the theme location and see all available menus there.

Comment: I have @WebElaine, thanks. The only Menu there is the one I want (with a class of 'menu-main-menu-container'). I can't find the rogue Menu anywhere. It gets invoked when I open site without being logged on (as anonymous user).